# Are there any online resources for practicing spoken Esperanto?

Tags: online-learning, esperanto, speaking

There are already a number of resources online to help learners improve their Esperanto reading, writing and aural comprehension, such as Duolingo, but I want to increase my confidence in *speaking* Esperanto.  Can anyone recommend any online resources that will allow me to converse in real-time with other Esperanto speakers and/or learners?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Telegram](https://telegram.org/) is a messaging application that allows you to send voice recordings. There is an [active community of Esperanto speakers](https://telegramo.org/) in Telegram, and they can correct your pronunciation if you ask them too. It is also a great place to ask people for a real-time conversation. For this, you can use programs such as [Skype](https://www.skype.com/en/), [Google Hangouts](https://hangouts.google.com/), [appear.in](https://appear.in/) and [Discord](https://discordapp.com/). Many programs exist and some of them do not require to download something or to create an account.

Comment: Is it possible to search for language learning communities for Telegram? Doing a search for Mongolian telegram community didn't work too well, because Mongolia still has literal telegrams.

Comment: Someone created a chat for each language in a [list of 60 languages](https://www.reddit.com/r/languagelearning/comments/4g5u4c/more_than_60_language_learning_chats_on_telegram/). The chats are probably not very active, but it is maybe a good start for finding a more active Telegram group for learners of a specific language. Sadly, Mongolian is not in this list.

Answer (score 14):

There seems to be an Esperanto group in Second Life that meet regularly and use the program's voice chat for conversations.

[Esperantujo en Dua Vivo](https://duavivo.wordpress.com/)

Answer (score 13):

You can buy spoken lessons with several Esperanto tutors with italki: [Find a Teacher.](https://www.italki.com/teachers/tutoring/esperanto)

Answer (score 10):

You might also want to take the leap with a face-to-face event.  I just found out about the [Paralela Universo](http://esperanto-usa.org/en/content/paralela-unverso-local-esperanto-events-20-north-american-cities-august-20-2016) event through the "[Language Stuff](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAFUQWc8ykcRCOES3NvvcfQ)" vlog on Youtube.

It looks to be open to beginners who haven't had the opportunity yet to talk with someone else.  It would take a little courage to leap in as an organizer for an Esperanto event.  I was considering organizing one myself because I didn't see one in my area until I went to the map.  I'm not usually so bold but what's the worst that could have happened?

Although the event started out for North America, there is nothing preventing you from starting one in your own country.  There are events on the map for Mexico and Cuba!  It's a leap...I know but you might be surprised at the interest generated in your area.  You would also rack up a lot of coolness points. :)

Comment: Thanks - there are face-to-face events in my region but they are scheduled only once a month. That's why I'm looking for ways I can practice online between meet-ups.

Answer (score 7):

If you've finished the Duolingo course (or equivalent), I'd highly recommend trying the new course [Ekparolu](http://www.edukado.net/ekparolu). It's a free course which consists of 10 lessons on the topics you choose. You tell them what you want to practice talking about and they'll match you with a tutor who will help you speak on that topic for a half hour!

Answer (score 5):

I used to use a site called [**Fluent in three Months**](http://www.fluentin3months.com/). It practically teaches you how to use a language and speak it properly, and encourages you to upload a video of yourself (set challenges) so you can get feedback on your pronunciation and speech. Very helpful website, you should check it out.

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning Jonna!

Answer (score 3):

I know an esperanto server on Discord " Ling & Lang " which propose an esperanto room : [Discord.](https://discordapp.com/invite/U7UDq)

Comment: Please try to expand your answer by adding perhaps some more information about the link you have in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

On [telegramo.org](http://telegramo.org) you can see various links for group chats about Esperanto on **Telegram**. Some of them are audio-conversation groups.

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can find tutors or Esperanto [language exchange partners](https://www.langademy.com/) at Langademy. They have a video chat room for Esperanto.

Answer (score 0):

There are some useful links [here](http://lernu.net/eo/forumo/temo/22934). Among others:

> **Chatrooms / Voice chat**
>
> - [/r/esperanto Discord server](https://discord.gg/8bdw6QZ) - A place where you can chat with other Esperanto speakers (via voice & text).
> - ['Skajpanoj' Facebook group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/skajpanoj/) for finding Skype contacts. [Here's a list of contacts](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17mC33EBWTYz6_0oYrEcs2VD9LzBCs5MG5bgG-dnLRUM/edit#gid=0) (you can add your details [here](http://www.esperanto.com.br/skajpo/index.html))
> - [telegramo.org](https://www.telegramo.org/) - chat with other esperantists